# Interstellar Space Near Future Betelguese Supernova

Tags: science-fiction, hard-science

I recently saw some new estimates about when Betelguese will go supernova and it got me thinking since a worldbuilding project I'm in the early stages of could plausibly see it happen given the timeline length I'm leaning towards.  I've seen tons of estimates about general types of damage a supernova could do to a planet within a few dozen light years or so.  I've also seen numbers suggesting that even supernova hundreds of light years away can be visible as a star even during full daylight.

So, question is this.  How far away from Betelguese when at its peak supernova brightness would one need to be for it to look about as bright as our sun does from Earth?  I've seen sources that say supernova give off about 1% of their energy in visible light, so I'm guessing this would actually still be pretty bad given the accompanying harsher stuff.  Humanity could easily settle the space in this area by the time it happens and knowledge of its impending nature could influence colonization efforts, even if shielding a planet wouldn't be *that* hard to do.

Comment: Part of the problem is that that 1% is not constant, it's more like a giant flash and then a gentle glow.  (gentle is relative).  What part of the timescale are you expecting this colonization to happen?  Link to brightness curve: http://community.dur.ac.uk/john.lucey/bridge/SN2015M_bridge.html (note the timescale)

Comment: Associated Question to be asked later...   If Betelguese's nova light reaches Earth during the first few years of a solar-sail based mission to Alpha Centauri, could it possible be coming from exactly behind our space ship such that it adds significantly to our speed and gets us there hundreds of years early?

Comment: Johannes Kepler saw a supernova in 1604. It was 20,000 ly away and was brighter than any star in the sky. But that's important. Betelgeuse is only 647 ly away and that's a distance ratio of only 31:1 (31X brighter than the brightest star in the sky != the sun... might != the moon). It's true that light brightness isn't linear, but I'm thinking Betelgeuse can't produce the boom necessary to rival our own sun (not that anything would survive to gainsay me). Hopefully @HDE226868 will chime in on this one. I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: Given that the star is estimated to go within the next 100,000 years and it's only hundreds of light years away, any decent expansion would put humanity much further out than this.  Which is what makes this idea interesting.  I'm imagining astronomers drooling themselves to dehydration over the idea of an event like this in human territory so they can study it and the aftermath up close.

Comment: There was a mass extinction here, the "hangenberg event" 370 million years ago. Researchers found hints that the UV-B radiation had very high levels for some 1000 years, maybe from a supernova 60 LY away. This is probably what would happen again. See: https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.2013774117

Comment: The 99% go into the creations of neutrinos, you don't need to worry about those. The 1% are all you need to worry about, and that's already more than enough.

Comment: @HenryTaylor No, Betelgeuse and Alpha Centauri are not on opposite sides of the Earth. I think what you'd have instead is your solar sail ship being "blown" off course in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at historical data.

[SN 1054](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN_1054) has an estimate of its distance from Earth at [6500 ± 1600 light years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_Nebula). It was visible by day.

Then there is [SN 1006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN_1006), which was bright enough to cast shadows! It happened about 7,200 light years away from us. Astronomers from the time estimated its brightness to be ¼ that of a full Moon:

> Egyptian astrologer and astronomer Ali ibn Ridwan, writing in a commentary on Ptolemy's Tetrabiblos, stated that the "spectacle was a large circular body, 2​½ to 3 times as large as Venus. The sky was shining because of its light. The intensity of its light was a little more than a quarter that of Moon light" (or perhaps "than the light of the Moon when one-quarter illuminated").

[The sun is about 400,000x brighter than a full Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude#Example:_Sun_and_Moon), so... about 1,600,000 brighter than SN 1006's supernova.

[The apparent brightness of a light source is proportional to the inverse of the square root of its distance to the observer](https://www.atnf.csiro.au/outreach/education/senior/cosmicengine/stars_luminosity.html). To make a supernova like SN 1006's as bright as our sun, we need to bring it about 1,600,000<sup>½</sup> closer to an observer on an Earth-like planet. That's about 1,265 closer, making it 5.7 light years away from the observer.

That would be... bad for the observer. Radiation follows the same inverse-square law as brightness. According to [XKCD What If no 73](https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/), a super nova blast from 1 AU away showers your retina with approximately a billion more times more energy than a nuclear fusion bomb pressed against your eyeball (just for comparison - I believe novas come from stars much larger than 1 AU so the scenario is unfeasible).

5.7 ly is about ~360,000 AU. So that would be like...

$$\frac{1}{360,000^{2}} = \frac{1}{129,600,000,000
}$$

Round down and it's a trillion times less radiation.

That means we reduce the radiation exposure to a trillionth of the 1 AU away supernova scenario. That's your retina getting 1/1,000th of the radiation of a fusion nuke blasting against it, which I believe most physicians would still consider unhealthy.